# CakePHP 2.0 : Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created

Tags: cakephp, nginx, php, chroot

following the installation of CakePHP 2.0 (modified, I said that I get the same problem on a clean install of cakephp 2.0) I found myself facing an error I have not been able to solve.

***configuration:***

**server** : debian weezy 7

**user** : test

**structure** : /wwwjail/siteroot/test/htdocs/[app/...]

**nginx configuration**

*cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/test*

```
server {
    listen IP:80 default;
    server_name domain.fr;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/test.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/test.error.log;

    autoindex off;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /wwwjail/siteroot/test/htdocs/;

    location ~ \.php$ {
                        try_files $uri =404;

                        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/wwwjail/siteroot/test/php-fpm.sock;

                        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

**php5-fpm configuration**

*cat /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/test.conf*

```
[test]
listen = /wwwjail/siteroot/test/php-fpm.sock
chroot = /wwwjail/siteroot/test/htdocs

user = test
group = test

listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.owner = test
listen.group = test
listen.backlog = -1
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_requests = 200
pm.status_path = /status_31337
request_terminate_timeout = 30s
catch_workers_output = yes
php_value[session.save_path] = /tmp
```

**Visible errors on the page:**

```
Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
Stack Trace

    ROOTlibROOTCakeROOTModelROOTDatasourceROOTDboSource.php line 262 → Mysql->connect()
    ROOTlibROOTCakeROOTModelROOTConnectionManager.php line 107 → DboSource->__construct(array)
    ROOTlibROOTCakeROOTModelROOTModel.php line 3221 → ConnectionManager::getDataSource(string)
    ROOTlibROOTCakeROOTModelROOTModel.php line 1108 → Model->setDataSource(string)
    ROOTlibROOTCakeROOTModelROOTModel.php line 3243 → Model->setSource(string)
    ROOTlibROOTCakeROOTModelROOTModel.php line 2696 → Model->getDataSource()
    ROOTappROOTControllerROOTAppController.php line 70 → Model->find(string, array)
    ROOTappROOTControllerROOTChallengesController.php line 57 → AppController->beforeFilter()
    [internal function] → ChallengesController->beforeFilter(CakeEvent)
    ROOTlibROOTCakeROOTEventROOTCakeEventManager.php line 248 → call_user_func(array, CakeEvent)
    ROOTlibROOTCakeROOTControllerROOTController.php line 670 → CakeEventManager->dispatch(CakeEvent)
    ROOTlibROOTCakeROOTRoutingROOTDispatcher.php line 184 → Controller->startupProcess()
    ROOTlibROOTCakeROOTRoutingROOTDispatcher.php line 162 → Dispatcher->_invoke(ChallengesController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
    ROOTappROOTwebrootROOTindex.php line 109 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
    ROOTindex.php line 43 → require(string)

CakePHP: the rapid development php framework
```

**Nginx Error log nginx :**

```
2013/12/24 12:23:03 [error] 17792#0: *535 open() "/wwwjail/siteroot/test/htdocs/css/default.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: myIP, server: domain.fr, request: "GET /css/default.css HTTP/1.1", host: "IP:80", referrer: "http://IP:80/"
2013/12/24 12:23:03 [error] 17792#0: *536 open() "/wwwjail/siteroot/test/htdocs/css/bootstrap.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: myIP, server: domain.fr, request: "GET /css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1", host: "IP:80", referrer: "http://IP:80/"
2013/12/24 12:23:03 [error] 17792#0: *537 open() "/wwwjail/siteroot/test/htdocs/css/jqplot.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: myIP, server: domain.fr, request: "GET /css/jqplot.css HTTP/1.1", host: "IP:80", referrer: "http://IP:80/"
2013/12/24 12:23:03 [error] 17792#0: *538 open() "/wwwjail/siteroot/test/htdocs/js/jqplot.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: myIP, server: domain.fr, request: "GET /js/jqplot.js HTTP/1.1", host: "IP:80", referrer: "http://IP:80/"
2013/12/24 12:23:03 [error] 17792#0: *534 open() "/wwwjail/siteroot/test/htdocs/js/holder.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: myIP, server: domain.fr, request: "GET /js/holder.js HTTP/1.1", host: "IP:80", referrer: "http://IP:80/"
2013/12/24 12:23:03 [error] 17792#0: *531 open() "/wwwjail/siteroot/test/htdocs/css/cake.generic.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: myIP, server: domain.fr, request: "GET /css/cake.generic.css HTTP/1.1", host: "IP:80", referrer: "http://IP:80/"
2013/12/24 12:23:03 [error] 17792#0: *531 open() "/wwwjail/siteroot/test/htdocs/img/cake.power.gif" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: myIP, server: domain.fr, request: "GET /img/cake.power.gif HTTP/1.1", host: "IP:80", referrer: "http://IP:80/"
2013/12/24 12:23:03 [error] 17792#0: *535 open() "/wwwjail/siteroot/test/htdocs/js/jqplot.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: myIP, server: domain.fr, request: "GET /js/jqplot.js HTTP/1.1", host: "IP:80", referrer: "http://IP:80/"
2013/12/24 12:23:03 [error] 17792#0: *531 open() "/wwwjail/siteroot/test/htdocs/js/holder.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: myIP, server: domain.fr, request: "GET /js/holder.js HTTP/1.1", host: "IP:80", referrer: "http://IP:80/"
2013/12/24 12:23:03 [error] 17792#0: *531 open() "/wwwjail/siteroot/test/htdocs/css/cake.generic.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: myIP, server: domain.fr, request: "GET /css/cake.generic.css HTTP/1.1", host: "IP:80", referrer: "http://IP:80/"
2013/12/24 12:23:03 [error] 17792#0: *531 open() "/wwwjail/siteroot/test/htdocs/img/cake.power.gif" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: myIP, server: domain.fr, request: "GET /img/cake.power.gif HTTP/1.1", host: "IP:80", referrer: "http://IP:80/"
```

On the **mysql database credentials are correct**, the user mysql user-test exist and full access to test.*

*cat /wwwjail/siteroot/test/htdocs/app/Config/database.php*

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'login' => 'user-test',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        'database' => 'test',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8'
    );
}
```

**Checking the connection with the config file of CakePHP (script found on stackoverflow)**

```
<?php
include("app/Config/database.php");
$config= new DATABASE_CONFIG();

$name = 'default';

$settings=$config->{$name};
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$settings['database'].';host='.$settings['host'];
$user = $settings['login'];
$password = $settings['password'];

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    echo "Connection succeeded with dsn: ". $dsn . "\n";
    $sql = 'SELECT id, title FROM posts';
    echo "Here is the contents of the table `posts:";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['id'] . "\t" . $row['title'] . "\n";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'PDO error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

====> return: `Connection succeeded with dsn: mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1 Here is the contents of the table`posts:`

**Checking socket with php.ini**

*grep -i  'default_socket' /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini*

```
default_socket_timeout = 60
pdo_mysql.default_socket= /wwwjail/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
mysql.default_socket = /wwwjail/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
mysqli.default_socket = /wwwjail/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

**Verification of the existence of the PDO extension.**

```
var_dump( extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') );
```

return => bool(true)

I hope I have provided much information about my problem. I am willing to perform various manipulations to test. (I think a problem server side configuration necessarily, although this configuration works for other basic applications connecting to mysql also).

Sincerely.

Answer (score 10):

In your **/app/Config/database.php** file,
change the following line:

```
'host' => 'localhost',
```

to:

```
'host' => '127.0.0.1',
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you haven't solved this yet:
I had the same error in my ubuntu 13.10 machine with the newest xampp downloaded directly from apachefriends. Try this:

Find your mysql.sock:

```
user@host /opt$ find . -name mysql.sock
/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

add it to your cakePHP database configuration file (cakePHP)/app/Config/database.php

```
'unix_socket' => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

To me, this finally resulted in my cake commands being able to be executed without the "*Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.*".

Comment: nice 1. Do you know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

In database.php you need to create a variable array for test database like so:

```
public $test = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root', // what ever you have as user 
    'password' => '', // what ever you have as pass
    'database' => 'test',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

Then crucially make sure you have an empty database called:

```
test
```

That error message is quite deceiving should really say "Missing database test" :) well in my case this was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and make sure you are using correct username and password

```
public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'user-test',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        'database' => 'test',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8'
    );
```

Comment: i've the same problem with localhost.
But with the test-file (Checking the connection with the config file of CakePHP (script found on stackoverflow)), now I have no "Connection succeeded with dsn: mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1 Here is the contents of the tableposts:" but "PDO error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" ..

Answer (score 0):

Create connection credentials to mysql via phpmyadmin if its set to be empty.
That worked for me