# Script connecting to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, cakephp

I want to set up a webpage where people can share pictures by using this script:
http://www.mediapubportal.com/

But whenever I install this script on my USBWebserver I get this Error (http://prntscr.com/7noi5v):

> Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

These are the install notes:

`-git clone git@github.com:dilab/media-pub-portal.git ~/media-pub-portal`

`-cd ~/media-pub-portal`

`-chmod -R 775 app/tmp/`

`-cp app/Config/database.php.default app/Config/database.php (supply correct value)`

I'm not using linux server (I'm using Win8 and USBWebserver) so I removed read only manually and configured database.php using notepad. But still no luck, whatever I do I keep getting the same error page.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: in `config.php` there is `debug_mode`. it is `0` by default . make it 1 and then refresh page. and then tell exact error through screen shot.thanks. just search `Configure::write('debug', 0);` and make it `Configure::write('debug', 2);` then save and then refresh the page

Comment: we are not support for every third party script on the planet

Comment: ^ better to ask them: https://github.com/dilab/media-pub-portal/wiki

Comment: @anantkumarsingh where could I find config.php
-Dagon noted
-ficuscr already did, but their support is kinda dead

Comment: @anantkumarsingh http://prntscr.com/7noslt this is the config file, can't find Configure::write('debug', 0);

Comment: sorry my mistake `project folder/app/config/core.php` ther it is present. please check

Comment: @anantkumarsingh http://prntscr.com/7novyn

Comment: for first error check this link answer(first one with comments):-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428546/warning-2-strtotime-function-strtotime-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-sys

Comment: @anantkumarsingh wow thank you! it works, only 2 more errors left http://prntscr.com/7np30k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all our discussion in comment you need to do following tings:-

1. Change your server timezone setting. For complete help check this link :- [Warning (2): strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428546/warning-2-strtotime-function-strtotime-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-sys)
2. rename `database.default.php` to `database.php` in your `project folder/app/config` and change credentials (database connection credentilas) in that file.
3. Refresh your page.

Comment: And also in first one check that all the credentials are correct or not. it seems that database name is not correct in first one.

Comment: Chaeck this link answer :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760567/cakephp-2-0-database-connection-mysql-is-missing-or-could-not-be-created. AND now please do somthing form yourself. try google. what are you doing. asking each and everything.